gRPC C++ client with custom server
I am quite new to gRPC. I created my model serving Docker image. The model has a unique pre-processing pipeline (hence not using the TensorFlow serving).
I was able to create an inference.proto:

// The request message containing the images. repeated keyword for list
message InferenceRequest {
    repeated int32 length = 1;
    repeated int32 width = 2;
    repeated int32 type = 3;
    repeated bytes image = 4;
}


message InferenceReply {
    repeated bytes pred = 1;
}

I followed a tutorial online to create a simple stub and send requests in Python which works fine. I need to change the client side to C++ now. I saw limited information about using it with TensorFlow Serving and C++ clients but nothing generic.
Any help is appreciated.

Does grpc.io: C++ help? Your proto doesn't include  any Services so I'm unsure whether you're using gRPC or just protobuf.

Thank you for the reply. It actually does. However, I am not able to reach the gRPC libs outside of the repo folder (a problem for another day). I have a simple service

When running it I see that the status.ok() is false and on the server side, there is no request received. here is the channel configuration on client side C++:
 RouteGuideClient guide(grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50052", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));

and here is the channel setup on the server side Pyhton:
    adddress = "0.0.0.0:50052"  # when the software is used locally, please use "localhost:50052"
    server.add_insecure_port(adddress)

anything you can help with?

Please consider updating your question with these details. It will (a) be easier to format the code; and (b) benefit others. From what I can glean, your C++ client code looks correct. I assume you're not seeing client-side errors and so I assume you've generated and bound the stubs correctly.
